# AspxCallback error

Tags: callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a Master-Detail GridView on my page and on DetailRow i have another grid, a aspxButton and a AspxCallback.

Here is the aspx codes:

```
    <dxe:ASPxButton ID="btn_StartWizard" runat="server"
     Text="Planlama Sihirbazını Çalıştır" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/BlackGlass/{0}/styles.css" CssPostfix="BlackGlass" AutoPostBack="false">
     <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){
     c_OpenPopup.PerformCallback(detail_Grid.cpdetail_Grid);}" />

    </dxe:ASPxButton>

    <dxcb:ASPxCallback ID="call_OpenPopup" runat="server" 
     ClientInstanceName="c_OpenPopup" Enabled="true" 
     oncallback="call_OpenPopup_Callback">
     <ClientSideEvents CallbackComplete="function(s, e) {
         if(e.result == &quot;true&quot;)
         {
        var indx = window.location.href.indexOf('MainCard.aspx');
        var url = window.location.href.substring(0,indx);
        var 
        var urlName = url + '?CoID=' + coID + '&amp;amp;BranchID=' + branchID + '&amp;amp;LineNo=' + LineNo + '&amp;amp;ConfMID=' + ID + '&amp;amp;uNum=' + UniqueNumber;
        var urlName = url;
        var valueCondition = window.showModalDialog(urlName,window,'dialogHeight:400px; dialogWidth: 820px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: Yes; resizable: No; status: Yes;');
         }
         else
         {
        alert('Bu siparişte herhangi bir planlama işi yok');
         }
        }" />
    </dxcb:ASPxCallback>
```

but when i clicked the button, Callback doesn't work. So i checked in "Firebug" and got this error: "**c_OpenPopup is not defined**". How can this be possible, that control has its ClientInstanceName set.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the button's AutoPostBack property to false.  Also, what is the goal to have the ASPxCallback within the Detail row template container?  If you expand several master rows, there will be several java script instances of the ASPxCallback on the page and all of them will have the same ClientInstanceName.  It means, that only the last one will work.

Comment: Button's AutoPostBack property is false. AspxCallback was outside of the grid, i just tried to see if it works in detail row, but it didn't.

Comment: I found the problem, On CallbackComplete event i wrote javascript but it doesnt work. So when i change the javascript code it worked.